# What tool do I use to administer MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have a phpBB installation on a shared hosting site, and I need to be able to run Sql queries on the underlying database from my remote (home) workstation.  I am checking the MySQL website for tools and I see that there are a few, but which one does what I have just described?

I am very familiar with MS Sql Management Studio, which I use daily on my day job to work with Sql Server databases, and something that allows me to edit Sql queries and run them against the remote MySQL database where my phpBB resides is what I need.

Which tool provided by MySQL does what I need?

Comment: You can find list of tools mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040661/gui-tools-for-mysql-5-0 I recommend to use SQLyog easy and popular

Answer (score 6):

There are three "official" Oracle tools for managing MySQL in the sense you describe, two of which are currently supported.

[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/) I assume is the administration tool that's most analogous to SSMS.

The [`mysql` command line client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html) is a console utility that allows you to issue queries and get results displayed in "ascii line drawing" tables.

[MySQL Query Browser](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/query/) is no longer officially supported, but still available for download and still compatible with newer versions of MySQL Server.  It's minimalistic in functionality compared to Workbench, but it's also substantially more lightweight.  It's essentially a GUI that's well-suited to a power user who doesn't want "help," just an interface that's more usable for running queries than the command line.  (As a DBA all day every day, I use Query Browser and the command line client almost exclusively.)

They're all free, of course.

There's nothing proprietary about MySQL Community Edition, so there's really nothing you can to do, administratively, to a MySQL server that specifically requires one of the official clients.  There are others out there, third party graphical tools that can provide, for all practical purposes, any functionality that "official" clients can provide.  They all have their respective strengths and weaknesses.

One thing to keep in mind, however, is that if you encounter any unusual behavior in any client, is that you should verify that behavior using the `mysql` command line client, to confirm whether it's the client you're using or the server behaving unexpectedly but consistently among different clients.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using **[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/)** for general monitoring and managing your mysql database instance.
Thing can be done in **MySQL Workbench** 
 - Database Design & Modeling
 - SQL Development
 - Database Administration
 - Database Migration
 - Server administration

For MySQL performance i recommend using [NEOR Profile SQL](http://www.profilesql.com/download/)  - is  great tool for profiling and optimizing the SQL queries. and is for free.

Answer (score 1):

PhpMyAdmin is a common GUI, web-based front-end for managing a MySQL database. Many shared hosting providers have PhpMyAdmin built in to their hosting, so check your hosting panel.

If you want to use a desktop app, and your hosting provides remote access, LibreOffice's Base program can remotely connect to a MySQL server (may require some fiddling).

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down. PhpMyAdmin is very capable and easy-to-use piece of software that comes preinstalled from many shared hosting providers on both Windows and Linux. Some shared hosts may not even allow remote connections to a MySql database (1&1 for example), meaning it may be the only choice.

Comment: I agree with you @cbojar -  i think he was looking for something with features. +1 for you !

Comment: I voted down because the question was "Which tool provided by MySQL," which I interpreted as "Which tool provided by Oracle," and this answer does not answer that question.  If the question had, instead, been "What is a good tool for administering MySQL" then we would need to close the question as off-topic, primarily opinion based, or off-topic, shopping list question.  MySQL Server is great ( MariaDB and Percona Server, too) but I personally think MySQL Workbench is a horrible, unstable, ill-conceived piece of dreadful ugly bloatware that Oracle should be ashamed of and nobody should use.